# inject style attribute based on parameter from Action in select item on JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, tags

I've been trying to find out the solution for hours but still failed :(

here's simple div on my JSP:

```
<div class="message" >
    HELLO USER!
</div>
```

I want to it to have style like this:

```
<div class="message" style="display : none;" >
    HELLO USER!
</div>
```

but this style is dependent on list object size which is coming from Struts Action, so this JSP is a result for the Action success.
I was trying smthg like just for test injecting value:

```
<s:set name="divStyle" value="display: none;" />
<div class="message" style="<s:property value="countyStyle" />" >
     HELLO USER!
</div>
```

and I tried:

```
<s:set name="divStyle" value="<s:if test="elementsFromAction.size > 1" >display: none;</s:if>" />
<div class="message" style="<s:property value="divStyle" />" >
     HELLO USER!
</div>
```

and:

```
<div class="message" style="<s:if test="elementsFromAction.size > 1" >display: none;</s:if>" />" >
     HELLO USER!
</div>
```

but it didn't work too :(

Could someone give an advice how to inject that style?
thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<s:set/>` snippet, you are nesting Struts tags, that is an error.

In your last snippet, there is a typo: you are closing an un-opened tag with `/>`.

Change it from

```xml
<div class="message" 
     style="<s:if test="elementsFromAction.size > 1">display: none;</s:if>" />" >
     HELLO USER!
</div>
```

to

```xml
<div class="message" 
     style="<s:if test="elementsFromAction.size > 1">display: none;</s:if>" >
     HELLO USER!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="message" style="${elementsFromAction.size gt 1 ? 'display : none;' : ''}" >
    HELLO USER!
</div>
```

Comment: thx but it didn't help ( maybe the reason was I don't include jstl tags on this JSP 'cause I use only special struts tags

Comment: This is a standard expression language, not jstl, strange it didin't work. Glad you got it resolved, though.

Answer (score 0):

Given another solution.

load your style into the data bean.

And in the page `onload` function you can handle them and translate them to what you like.

which can avoid some trouble when the logic is too complicated.